# Unhiding rows not working in Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel

I noticed a strange behaviour in Excel 2007 files.

In an empty file, I select a number of rows and hide them. Then if I select the first and last row where all rows are hidden and unhide them, everything is fine.

If I want to do this in a filled Excel file, it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I have it now. You have to select the first and last row then move the cursor to get a symbol with up and down arrows and one bar. Then doubleclick and all rows are unhided. If you have the symbol with up and down arrows and two bars you only unhide one row.

Comment: Potentially better: select, right click > unhide

Comment: For some reason unhiding only works if filters are applied and then removed. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Ctrl+A to select all rows and go to "Home > Format > Hide & Unhide > Unhide Rows"
```

1. Make sure you don't have frozen panes
2. Make sure there is no filter active
3. sometimes rows are not hidden but have a very small height. Ctrl+A to select all rows and go to "Home > Format > Row Height" and fill in a height.

Hope it helps.

Comment: "Make sure there is no filter active"  - figured this out on my own, but would have been much easier to have found this answer first.  Also "No" is the operative word. If you have three filters on, then you have to remove all three before you can unhide multiple rows at the same time.